# One line code for Converting list to dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there a one liner code for converting the following list/string to map, basically counting all chars and storing in map.

```
lst = 'leet'

map ={'l':1,'e':2,'t':1}
```

what i did so far

```
for i in lst:
    if i not in map:
        map[i] = 1
    else:
        map[i]+=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("leet")
Counter({'e': 2, 'l': 1, 't': 1})
```

Source: https://realpython.com/python-counter/

Answer (score 1):

`from collections import Counter; c = Counter(lst)` since you said must be one-liner :)

Answer (score 0):

`{letter: "leet".count(letter) for letter in "leet"}` might work

Comment: it does, but the `str.count` is a little bit inefficient when a letter is repeated multiple times in a str. also the `list()` constructor can be removed in this case.